# Проблемы безопасности

Tags: грамотная-речь

Копаюсь тут в настройках "хрома" (браузера) и обратил внимание на эту: *автоматически отправлять в Google информацию о возможных проблемах безопасности.*

И я задумался, не звучит ли странно это словосочетание *"проблемы безопасности",* хотя и понятно в целом, что за ним стоит.

Comment: Действительно парадокс. Безопасности нет, а проблемы безопасности есть. Кстати, "под ним стоит" не говорят. Или за ним стоит, или под этим понимается/подразумевается.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно!!) Это не описка, я просто привык так говорить и даже не задумывался, что это неправильно. Порылся в гугле, чтобы убедиться, что Вы правы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подобные выражения (проблема *чего*) применяют как минимум в двух разных аспектах: проблема, заключающаяся в факте существования названного (проблема ИГИЛ) и проблема, принадлежащая названной области (проблемы физики). В данном случае второе: подразумеваются проблемы "из области" безопасности (ситуации, влияющие на степень безопасности), которые могут потребовать оперативного решения (угроза сохранности данных, проблема спама, вирусной атаки и т. п. - здесь слово "проблема" применено  в первом аспекте: в родительном падеже наименование нежелательного события). Поэтому такое выражение допустимо. Можно было бы его обойти, назвав "угрозой" безопасности (дат. падеж), однако фирмы - разработчики программ избегают резких выражений, связанных с работоспособностью их продукции, например, "аварийные" варианты загрузки операционной системы у "Майкрософт" дипломатично именуются "безопасным режимом" загрузки.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Я тоже думал, что имеются в виду проблемы именно из области безопасности, просто я не нашёл, как это сформулировать и какое дать определение, чтобы подошло.